# How do i switch between 3 image view in a uiimage with a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Basically I need a button that switches between 3 images,I am not sure how I can accomplish this and I have been trying to look for a way.

Comment: Are you looking for a button that switches images each time you press it?

Comment: are you talking about a normal, hover and pressed image for the button?

Comment: Not exactly, I need a button that switches between 3 images each time user presses it.

Comment: For example I push a button it goes to a picture of an apple, than an orange than a tomato.

Comment: Instead of storing the current index in an instance variable; you can make a call to the indexOfObject to the array with the image that is already displayed;

Comment: But that would be a bit of an overkill. An instance variable is a nice optimization that prevents looking up the object over and over in the array.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is an array and modulo arithmetic:

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, nil];

int idx = 0;

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:idx];
    idx = (idx + 1) % images.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad you could take an UIImageView and add it to the view.  Then take an NSArray of UIImages and add the image at index 0 to the UIImageView as it's default image.  Then create a custom button and every time it is clicked it will rotate to a new image in the NSArray.  Does this help?